# Swift/Firebase: Order table view by child Path keys?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just stumbled upon a rather tricky problem, where I am trying to order Firebase data by a childs key. Basically, my database looks like this, and I want to only show info of the user(s) that has 'Football' as their hobby - from the 'hobby' childpath, but also displaying their other hobbies as well as other info such as the team:

```
root {
    userID {
        name: Michael
        country: USA
        hobbies {
            Football {
                team: Barcelona
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have experimented with both `queryOrderedByKey.queryEqualToValue("Football")`, but I am not sure wether this will retrieve data from only the users who has Football set as their hobby, or just mess up.. Any ideas on how I would approach this? I have tried using the code, but it didn't seem to work.

The reason for wanting to display this, is that I want it to be displayed in a table view, with all user information, and that you can search by ex. hobbies and teams.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your structure:

```
user_id_0 {
    name: Michael
    country: USA
    hobbies
       hobby_id_0
         name: Football
         team: Barcelona
       hobby_id_1
         name: Curling
         team: Ice Slippers
}
```

You can get to data via queries or deep queries but you may want to consider denormalizing the data and pull the hobbies out for each user, depending on how many other levels of children is needed.